# Attaching two functions to event handler

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, event-handling

I am working on html 5 canvas and I am trying to take two points as input from users and then made a line pass through them. For it I need to attach two functions to event handler but it isn't working. Following is my codes for JavaScript and html 5.
Also is there any way to accomplish it?
Browser used: Google chrome

JavaScript Code:

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var graph = c.getContext("2d");
var posX = 100;
var posY = 50;
var finalX = posX;
var finalY = posY;
var array = [[]];
var i = 0;
c.width = window.innerWidth;
c.height = window.innerHeight;
graph.strokeRect(100,50,1000,500)

// for making graph 
while(finalY < 550)
{
    finalY +=10;
    graph.beginPath();
    graph.moveTo(posX , finalY);
    graph.lineTo(posX + 1000, finalY);
    if(finalY == 300) {
        graph.lineWidth = 2;
        graph.strokeStyle = "#000000";

    } else {
        graph.strokeStyle = "#000000";
        graph.lineWidth = 1;
    }
    graph.stroke();
}
while(finalX <1100) {
    finalX += 10;
    graph.beginPath();
    graph.moveTo(finalX, posY);
    graph.lineTo(finalX, posY + 500);
    if(finalX == 600) {
        graph.lineWidth = 2;
        graph.strokeStyle = "#000000";

    } else {
        graph.lineWidth = 1;
        graph.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    }

    graph.stroke();
}

// for making rectangle wherever the user clicks
function rect(e) {
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var x = e.clientX;
    var y = e.clientY;
    var j = 0;
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255,0,0)";
    ctx.fillRect(x,y,5,5);
    array[i][j] = x;
    array [i][j+1] = y;
}

var joinPts = function() {
    graph.beginPath();
    graph.moveTo(array[0][0],array[0][1]);
    graph.lineTo(array[1][0],array[1][1]);
    graph.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    graph.lineWidth = 2;
    graph.stroke();
}

function add() {
    i+=1;
}

function combine() {
    rect();
    add();
}

function initialise() {
    c.addEventListener("click", function (){combine();}, false);
    // c.addEventListener("click", rect , false); This way also it isn't working
    // c.addEventListener("click", add , false);
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Canvas!!</title>
</head>
<body style="background:white" onload="initialise()">
    <canvas id="myCanvas" style="background:#f6f6f6"></canvas>

    <button name="Reset" type="reset" onclick="window.location.reload();">Reset</button>
    <button name="Join" type="submit" onclick="joinPts">Join</button>

    <footer>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </footer>   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually call the `joinPts` function in your `onclick`.

Replace:

```
onclick="joinPts"
```

With:

```
onclick="joinPts()"
```

Also, your `combined` function is lacking the `e` event parameter:

```
function combine(e) { // Accept a `e` parameter,
    rect(e);         // and pass it to `rect`.
    add();
}

function initialise() {
    c.addEventListener("click", combine, false); // No need to wrap `combine` in a function
}
```

Comment: What's not working? Are you getting any errors? What _is_ and what _isn't_ happening?

Comment: JoinPts function should join the two points marked on graph by the user. But it isn't joining it. 
c.addEventListener("click", combine, false); // this statement not even marking the point on graph
while following code is marking the point but not joining them
c.addEventListener("click", rect , false)
c.addEventListener("click", add , false);

Comment: Is the `combine` function being called? is `rect`?

Comment: If rect is called then atleast points are marked on graph
but if combine is called then even points are not marked on graph

Comment: Can you place an `alert` in `combine` and in `rect`? I believe the functions are being called like they should, but that there's something going wrong in the `rect` function.

Comment: Alert is working. combine is accessed but it is accessed only first time a user clicks, second time combine is not accessed.